Convex combination of equidistant curves
Say we have three curves $\gamma, \delta, \varepsilon : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^n$ such that the distances $\lVert \gamma(t) - \delta(t) \rVert$ and $\lVert \gamma(t) - \varepsilon(t) \rVert$ are constant with respect to $t \in \mathbb R$. How can I go about proving that the distance
$$
\lVert \gamma(t) - (1-a)\, \delta(t) - a \, \varepsilon(t) \rVert
$$
is also constant? More generally, if we have curves $\gamma, \gamma_1, \dots, \gamma_n$ such that $\lVert \gamma(t) - \gamma_i(t) \rVert$ is constant for all $i = 1, \dots n$, can it be proven that
$$
\left \lVert \gamma(t) - \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \, \gamma_i(t) \right\lVert
$$
is constant, given that $a_i \geq 0$ for all $i = 1, \dots, n$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i = 1$? I really feel like this should be true after making a few drawings on paper, but I have no idea how to prove or disprove it. Any hints?

This is untrue.
Consider $\gamma_0(t) = (t,0)$, $\gamma_1(t) = (t-1,0)$ and $\gamma_2(t) = (t- \cos t, -\sin t)$, for $t \in \Bbb R$.
Then
\begin{align}
\gamma_0(t) - \gamma_1(t) &= (1,0), \\
\gamma_0(t) - \gamma_2(t) &= (\cos t, \sin t), \\
\gamma_0(t) - \frac{1}{2}\gamma_1(t) - \frac{1}{2}\gamma_2(t) &= \left(\frac{1+\cos t}{2}, \frac{\sin t}{2}\right).
\end{align}
Therefore, for all $t$, $\|\gamma_0(t) - \gamma_1(t)\| = \|\gamma_0(t) - \gamma_2(t)\| = 1$, but
$$
\left\|\gamma_0(t) - \frac{1}{2}\gamma_1(t) - \frac{1}{2}\gamma_2(t) \right\| = \sqrt{\frac{1+\cos t}{2}},
$$
which is not constant.
Presumably in your sketches, you drew "parallel curves", which mislead you, while you can actually consider curves that wrap around each others.

Thanks for the nice counterexample! The motivation behind the question comes from physics, regarding rigid body motion of a system of point particles. Using the condition that $\lVert r_i - r_j \rVert$ must be constant for all trajectories $r_i, r_j : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^3$, I'm trying to show that $\lVert r_i - r \rVert$ is also necessarily constant, where $r = \frac{\sum_i m_i r_i}{\sum_i m_i}$ is the center of mass. What assumptions did I miss in my original question then?

@markusas In my counterexample, we do not have that $|\gamma_1-\gamma_2|$ is constant. This is not asked in your question!

@markusas The actual statement should be like this: if $|\gamma_1-\gamma_2|$ is constant over time and $\lambda \in [0,1]$, then $|\gamma_1-\gamma_0|$ and $|\gamma_2-\gamma_0|$ are constant over time, where $\gamma_0 = (1-\lambda) \gamma_1 + \lambda \gamma_2$ (and similarly for higher number of curves)
